# Using Multiprocessing, how to Apply() within each CPU

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have to run a process on about 2 million IDs, for which I am trying to use MultipleProcessing.

My sample data, stored in dataframe `df` looks like (just presenting 3 rows):

```
      c_id
0     ID1
1     ID2
2     ID3
```

My parallelize code is as follows:

```
def parallelize(data,func,parts=cpu_count()):
    if data.shape[0] < parts:
        parts = data.shape[0]
    data_split = np.array_split(data,parts)
    pool = Pool(parts)
    parallel_out = pd.concat(pool.map(func,data_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return parallel_out
```

A sample process that I want to run on all the ID's is to add my first name each ID.

There are two pieces of codes that I tested.

First: Using a for loop and then calling the `parallelize` function, as follows:

```
def pooltype1(df_id):
    dfi=[]

    for item in df_id['c_id']:
        dfi.append({'string': str(item) + '_ravi'})
    dfi = pd.DataFrame(df)
    return dfi

p = parallelize(df,pooltype1,parts=cpu_count())
```

The output is as expected and the index of each is 0, confirming that each ID went into a different cpu (cpu_count() for my system > 3):

```
      string
0     ID1_ravi
0     ID2_ravi
0     ID3_ravi
```

and the **runtime is 0.12 secs**.

However, to further speed it up on my actual (2 million) data, I tried to replace the for-loop in the `pooltype1` function by a `apply` command and then calling the `parallelize` function as below:

```
# New function
def add_string(x):
    return x + '_ravi'

def pooltype2(df_id):
    dfi = df_id.apply(add_string)
    return dfi

p = parallelize(df,pooltype2,parts=cpu_count())
```

Now index of the output was not all zero

```
      string
0     ID1_ravi
1     ID2_ravi
2     ID3_ravi
```

and to my surprise the **runtime jumped to 5.5 sec**. This seems like apply was executed on the whole original dataframe and not at a cpu level.

So, while doing `pool.map` do I have to use a for-loop (as in pooltype1 function) or is there a way the `apply` can be applied within each cpu (hoping that it will further reduce run time). If one can do the `apply` at a cpu level, please do help me with the code.

Thank you.

Comment: `apply` isn't going to make a big difference anyway, it is essentially a loop underneath the hood

Comment: Is this the actual function you need? If so, just use `df['c_id'] + '_ravi'`

Comment: Thanks for the response juanpa.arrivillaga but this is not the actual function that I need.